# $Y\times_X Y$ a closed subscheme of $\hat{Y\times Y}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

This question comes from me reading Van den Bergh's paper(page 12 middle of the proof).https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211064

Let $X=Spec R$ where $R$ is a complete local ring over an algebraically closed field $k$,$x$ its unique closed point. $Y$ an $X$-scheme. Define $\hat{Y\times Y}=(Y\times Y)\times_{X\times X} Spec \mathcal{\hat{O}}_{X\times X,(x,x)}$ (here $\times$ without subscript means over $k$).

It is claimed in the paper that

> $Y\times_X Y$ is a closed subscheme of $\hat{Y\times Y}$.

Here are my questions:

1.How do we understand $\hat{Y\times Y}$? What is its geometric meaning?

2.Why is the above statement true?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we can equivalently describe $Y \times_X Y$ as $(Y \times Y) \times_{X \times X} X$, where $X \to X \times X$ is the diagonal map $\Delta_X$ (this can easily be seen from the functor of points point of view, or by a quick diagram-theoretic argument). Note that $\Delta_X$ is a closed immersion since $X$ is affine.

Thus (by base change) it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Spec} \hat{\mathcal O}_{X \times X, (x,x)} \to X \times X$ induces a closed immersion $\Delta_X \colon X \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \hat{\mathcal O}_{X \times X,(x,x)}$. On the level of rings, this is the map
\begin{align*}
(R \otimes_k R)^\hat{} &\to R,\label{1}\tag{1}\\
r_1 \otimes r_2 &\mapsto r_1r_2,
\end{align*}
where the completion is along the maximal ideal corresponding to $R \otimes R \twoheadrightarrow R \twoheadrightarrow k$. But the map (\ref{1}) is already surjective before completing, so it will remain so after. $\square$

Thus, the geometric intuition behind $Y \hat{\times} Y$ is that it is the base change of the $(X\times X)$-scheme $Y \times Y$ along the completion $\operatorname{Spec} \hat{\mathcal O}_{X \times X, (x,x)} \to X \times X$.

**Example.** Let $R = k[[x]]$. It is instructive to think about the difference between $k[[x]] \otimes k[[y]]$ and $k[[x,y]]$ (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1773613)). The above procedure takes the variety $Y \times Y$ over $k[[x]] \otimes k[[y]]$ and spits out the variety $Y \hat{\times} Y$ over $k[[x,y]]$.

Comment: Thanks Remy! Great answer. Just one more thing, I understand how we can describe $Y \times_X Y$ as $(Y \times Y) \times_{X \times X} X$ using diagram theoretic argument, but not sure about what you mean by the functor points of view, could you elaborate a little on that?

Comment: In order to prove that the two fibred products agree, by Yoneda it suffices to prove that their $R$-points agree for any ring $R$. But then you're just proving an equality of sets (rather than schemes), so you can use the explicit description of the fibred product in $\underline{\operatorname{Set}}$. This is a standard method in algebraic geometry (and other areas) to reduce diagram-theoretic statements to set-theoretic ones.